# History of the Garani village in FYROM

Tags: etymology

I'm interested in the origins of the Garani (Гарани, Garana) village located in the west of the former Yugoslav Republic Of Macedonia (FYROM).

What is the origin/etymology of the name? When do we estimate its foundation date is?

There are also 3 villages with this name in Belarus and one in Russia. Is there any connection?

I haven't found any information in English, except for the French Wikipedia article. There's a bit more info in the Albanian one and we can assume that the village is at least 500 years old. I have no knowledge of Macedonian, Albanian or Russian so I'm very limited in my research...

[French Wikipedia article on Garani](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garani)
[Russian Wikipedia article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8)

Comment: Do you have a reference you can post that shows the age you indicate for this village?  I can't seem to find any historical info.

Comment: @user2448131 The Albanian Wikipedia article mentions a mosque dating from the 15th century, no sources though...

Answer (score 2):

It appears this may be based on [Gorani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorani_people), which are an ethnic group found throughtout the [Gora Region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gora_(region)). (Searching led to [one site](https://mkd.geonamebase.com/node/1914) which stated Gorani as an alternate to Garani).  The village name may also just refer to location, as the translation for Gorani is 'highlanders', and Gora means mountains. So this may just be regional for 'Mountain village'.

The reference to the Gora region, even though this village is not within it, is for a possible root to the name of the village, or possibly a namesake type situation.  The U.S. is full of towns that were named, by their founders, after their home towns in England or Europe.  Perhaps the founders of Garani came from this region or were of that ethnic group.

Comment: Thanks, interesting finding. Do you have the link of the website stating Gorani as an alternate to Garani?

Comment: Edited site where Gorani listed as alternate into answer.

Comment: I am looking at the Gora region and it doesn't seem to include the Garani village, it's about 30-40 km further south...

Comment: @nyg I updated answer about Gora region.